# nbconvert doesn't respect jupyter center alignment

Tags: python, jupyter, nbconvert

i have a jupyter notebook i want to convert to html without python code.

In the notebook i aligned plot and tables using this piece of code

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML 

CSS = """
.output {
    align-items: center;
}
"""

HTML('<style>{}</style>'.format(CSS))
```

And indeed this plot is aligned correctly

[image]

When i launch:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to html --no-input myreport.ipynb
```

the resulting html file is showing items left aligned.
Why??

Answer (score 1):

This is likely occurring due to missing commands in the input or could also be an error within the library.

This thread seems to have an acceptable solution - [Figures are left-aligned when converting --to html -no-input #915](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/915#issuecomment-564554025)

You may also want to update the libraries to the newer versions.

Comment: libraries are updated. Already seen that link, no lucky with that

Comment: @MarcoFumagalli Not sure where else this could be going wrong. You can search around and even raise an issue on the github project to attract the attention of the authors. One of the solutions I can think of is to use scrips such as TamperMonkey to align it using css - not efficient but will solve the problem